# How to programatically take a screenshot on BlackBerry 10 using cascades?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Is it possible to take the screenshot using Blackberry 10 cascades API?

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339379/qt-mdi-app-with-opengl-how-to-grab-a-valid-screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Screenshot API is now on SDK 10.2 Beta: [http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*system*_screenshot.html](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__system__screenshot.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible right now, but is something being considered for post launch.

Comment: hi @pbernhardt, thanks for the information. I shall keep my eyes open to the updates.