# Cascades bb10 how to taking screenshot with API Level 10.0

Tags: blackberry, screenshot, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Is there any other way to take screenshot by code ?

I read this post [How to programatically take a screenshot on BlackBerry 10 using cascades?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123438/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-blackberry-10-using-cascades)
and i read this too https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__screenshot.html

but i need to take the screenshot with minimum API level 10.0.
is there any other way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taking screenshots is available since API level 10.2. All BlackBerry devices recently received an update to OS 10.3.1. So, there should be no problem requiring API level 10.2 in an app.