# Produce video from OpenGL C program

Tags: c, windows, opengl, video

I have a C program that runs a scientific simulation and displays a visualisation in an OpenGL window. I want to make this visualisation into a video, which will eventually go on YouTube.

**Question:** What's the best way to make a video from a C / OpenGL program?

The way I've done it in the past is to use a screen capture program, but this is very labour-intensive (have to start/stop the screen capture program, save the video file, etc...). It seems like there should be a way to automate the process of making a video from within the C program. Then I can leave it running overnight and have 20 videos to look through in the morning, and choose the best one to put on YouTube.

YouTube [recommend](http://www.youtube.com/t/howto_makevideo) "MPEG4 (Divx, Xvid) format at 640x480 resolution".

I'm using [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) 3.7.6_3, if that makes a difference. I can change windowing system if there's a good reason.

I'm running Windows (XP), so would prefer answers that work on Windows, but Linux answers are ok too. I can use Linux if it's not possible to do the video stuff easily on Windows. I have a friend who makes a .png image for each frame of the video and then stitches them together using "mencoder" on Linux.

Comment: Saving individual frames and doing the conversion to video in an external tool (mencoder is probably a good guess) sounds like the best solution to me.

Comment: see bigger discussion on topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154730/capturing-video-out-of-an-opengl-window-in-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the glReadPixels function (see [example](http://eonstrife.wordpress.com/2007/06/02/taking-a-screenshot-from-an-opengl-application/))

But if the stuff you are trying to display is made of simple objects (i.e. spheres, rods, etc..), I would "export" each frame into a [POV-ray](http://povray.org/) files, render these, and then make a video out of these pictures. you will reach a much higher quality like that.

Comment: Not that it matters too much for this particular instance, but using PBOs is more efficient than glReadPixels() as PBOs allow for DMA.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 3rd party application like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) to do the job for you.

> Fraps can capture audio and video up
>   to 2560x1600 with custom frame rates
>   from 1 to 120 frames per second!
>
> All movies are recorded in outstanding
>   quality.

They have video samples on the site. They seem good.

**EDIT:**

You could execute a tool to record the screen from your C application by calling it like  `system("C:\screen_recorder_app.exe -params")`. Check [camstudio](http://camstudio.org/blog/camstudio-command-line-v01-released), it has a command line version.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to just be a regular screen capture program. Can you run this from a C program?