# capturing openGL graphics in a video

Tags: opengl, ocaml, video-capture, glut

I have written an openGL application and would like to produce a video of the graphics shown on the Glut window. Do you know how to do it?

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154730/capturing-video-out-of-an-opengl-window-in-windows) at SO, I know that one possible solution is to use glReadPixels to get the frames that were rendered by openGL and then use the [FFmpeg library](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to produce the video. I don't really know how to use FFmpeg, so I'm not sure how I could write a program which takes the frames and outputs the video. Although the link is broken in the original question, I've found [this example](http://blender.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.42a/apiexample_8c-source.html) of video encoding, that may be useful for anyone trying to help.

Two questions:

1. How can I use FFmpeg to write a program which takes frames and outputs a video?
2. My application is written in OCaml, so I'm using `lablgl` and `lablglut`. Any ideas on how the FFmpeg ideas could be implemented in that case?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to write your frames to individual PNG files, then use the command-line `ffmpeg` tool to encode this into a video.

Comment: How do I produce PNGs from within openGL? Also, that will produce tens of thousands of files. Isn't that a bit too much?

Comment: Not from within OpenGL; you'd still have to use `glReadPixels` to grab the framebuffer contents, and then use libpng to compress the raw pixels. Tens of thousands of files is a lot, but hopefully nothing your machine can't handle. I've used similar techniques to create a video of several minutes, and it was no problem.

Comment: With the method `png_write_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, png_transforms, NULL)`? But, if `glReadPixels` returns void, how I can use `libpng` to access the frame just read?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml It writes to the buffer that you set up and hand to it via the `void *data`. How that would work in OCaml I have no idea, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the png answser : output to bmp. Create a white image of the same size in Paint (or whatever is available on mac), open it with notepad, isolate the file header (for 800*600 it's 42 4D 36 F9 15 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00-00 00 20 03 00 00 58 02 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00-00 00 00 F9 15 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 ), append results of glReadPixels, flush, close.

So yeah, lots of files, but usually not a problem since most openGL apps don't use the hard drive too much.

( I know, it's quite dirty, but it's the simplest method to implement - I did it on the train once, without any documentation )

Answer (score 0):

To capture video for a demo the best way is probably [fraps](http://www.fraps.com)

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm on MacOS. =/

Comment: Actually, .kkapture is often better if there is no user interaction http://www.farb-rausch.de/~fg/kkapture/ . But still, MacOS :/