# Convert Text to Video (mp4 or mov or flv)

Tags: c#, video

Is there any library which allows to convert text to video in C# just like we have text to speech.

Comment: I want to do it programatically, Ithink using Flash one has to create fla files manually

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`System.Graphics.DrawString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) to create images from text. To turn them into videos, you might have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251467/how-can-i-create-a-video-from-a-directory-of-images-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean? Do you mean convert the string itself to a video of some length? If so, [Job B's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764184/convert-text-to-video-mp4-or-mov-or-flv/3764245#3764245) answer is a good starting point. Or do you mean convert (TTS) the text to audio and convert the audio to a movie? You can use [System.Speech.Synthesis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.aspx) to convert text to audio. Or a combination?