# Decode GIF frames and encode to a video C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm developing an app that consumes the 8tracks API. Some of the playlists have gifs as the playlist art and I would like to have those gifs play in the app. UWP does not support native gif playback so i'm trying to figure out a way to make them play. So far I have tried using XamlAnimatedGif but its performance is bad, especially on phones.

Now i'm using Giphy API to upload the gif which also creates an mp4 version of the gif and plays back smoothly in a MediaElement. I can play up to 10 MP4s at a time smoothly(not that ill ever need that many playing at a given time). I'm wondering if i can eliminate Giphy and have the computer/phone just take each frame from the gif and then encode them to an mp4(or other video file). Is this a good option? what would be any cons to doing this vs. what im already doing with Giphy? If i decide to at least try this Is there any where i can read up on decoding the gifs to frames and encoding them to a video?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the GifBitmapDecoder to get the frames

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapdecoder(v=vs.90).aspx

and there are a number of options here to convert stills to a video:

[How can I create a video from a directory of images in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251467/how-can-i-create-a-video-from-a-directory-of-images-in-c)