# How to convert a GIF file to a video file and save it to disk in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gif, mp4

I am making an app in Unity on Windows 10. I want to convert a .gif file to a .mp4 file. But the problem is, I have NO clue how to do that, I searched online and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594306/decode-gif-frames-and-encode-to-a-video-c-sharp), but I have no idea how to do that. Also, I tried to search how to get the frames of a GIF file and it gave a solution for Windows Form application Not what I want to do!
Also I have another problem:
I am unable to use Bitmap in unity for some reason. I downloaded the code from [this website](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659027/How-to-Split-a-GIF-Frame-By-Frame-and-Save-Them-to), but I got multiple errors. My solution to those errors:

1. I downloaded System.Drawing.Common from NuGet, but I still got the same errors.
2. I even referenced System.Drawing to my project from Assemblies.
   None of them worked for me.
   Expected Answer for this question is(Any one):
3. How to use the following in unity:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("mygif.gif")
clip.write_videofile("myvideo.mp4")
```

2. How to Convert .gif to .mp4 and save it to disk in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ffmpeg.org/

```
ffmpeg -f gif -i infile.gif outfile.mp4
```

Within unity you can use .net [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0) class to launch the conversion.